# How to determine the current widget's parent container (sidebar widget id)

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I have several custom widgets that are installed as part of my theme. I'd like to execute conditional code inside each widget's admin panel (not the public side, I'm just interested in the admin panel inside function form($intance)), depending on which sidebar the widget is inserted into.

How can I obtain a reference to the current sidebar id which holds the widget, from within the widget's function form($instance) handler?

Comment: So, are you looking for the sidebar id while in the admin area or on the front-end?

Comment: In the admin area, inside my function form($instance){} branch

Answer (score 3):

If your widgets use the widget API you should have the following method in your widget class...

```
function widget($args, $instance){
    //output html here...
}
```

`$args['id']` will hold the id of the current sidebar.

Comment: I'm trying to execute code inside the widget admin panel, not on the public side view. The function is function form($instance) so I do not have access to the $args in this context.

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- I missed that comment.

Answer (score 2):

If your sidebar has a name, you can retrieve the sidebar name using `get_sidebar( $name )`

inside the widget itself, try this:

```
global $wp_registered_widgets, $wp_registered_sidebars;
$sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
if($sidebars_widgets["sidebar-1"]) echo 'hooray';
```

Comment: My sidebar has a name and an ID, however, get_sidebar($name) returns nothing when called inside of function form($instance)

Comment: sidebar name refers to custom sidebar template, for example: sidebar-right.php

Comment: Sean, this is inside the widget admin area, not on the public site.

Comment: just added the snippet you can use inside the widget itself. That should work for admin area.

Comment: Sean, should "sidebar-1" be the "name" or the "id" of the widget. Name never echoes, but using sidebar-id, I get echo on all instances of the widget, whether in the sidebar represented by the sidebar-id or not.

Comment: "sidebar-1" is supposedly the target widget id you want. widget must be placed inside the target sidebar, and data must be in db before it can be realized. Data structure is sidebars_widgets -> wp_inactive_widgets -> inactive widget list -> sidebar-1 -> active widget list....

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no easy way of doing that as of WP 3.2. In general, the widgets admin screen isn't very extensible.

You'll just have to make two widget classes and instruct users where to put each.

Comment: Ouch, say it aint so, Joe.